# How to check the result of cron job

Tags: ubuntu, python, cron, ubuntu-14.04

I am new to cron tab.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS.

I searched Google and stackoverflow, but could not find good answers.

I am trying to check the status of two newly-added cron jobs.

I tried command line **grep –i cron /var/log/syslog**  , but it shows something not understanding what they are saying.

I added two cron jobs (in orange boxes), and I think I did correctly (in terms of timing and putting correct folder location and name).

Both are Python files.

Do I have to create other type of files beside just putting Python files inside folder?

I am not sure what **/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime** is for.

[[image: crontab image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fccv.png)

Any suggestions to find some better way to see the results of jobs?

Comment: You should make the job save a log (and remember to rotate it) or send you an email (if there's any output, you should already be receiving an email).

Comment: Any output generated - stderr or stdout - by a cron job should get mailed to the user via the internal mail system.  I would recommend redirecting all output to a log file or stdout and stderr to different log files, and in your scripts that you call via cron add in some extra "here's what's happening" output.

Comment: For small things yiu can also use the `logger` command to log to /var/log/syslog/